# The singularity of a family of matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $l\ge2$ be an even integer, $\zeta$ be a primitive $l$th root of unity in $\mathbb{C}$. Is it true for any $\alpha=(\alpha_1,\dots,\alpha_l)$ and $\beta=(\beta_1,\dots,\beta_l)$ such that $\alpha_j^2=-1$ and $\beta_k^2=1$, that the $l\times l$ matrix $M$ with entry $(1+(-1)^k\alpha_j)\beta_k^j\zeta^{jk}$ in $j$th row and $k$th column nonsingualr?

Comment: Do you have some reason for thinking this might be true?

Comment: @GerryMyerson Yes, it stems from the answer of Lev Borisov to a question [here](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/141281/dimension-of-a-homogeneous-polynomial-system)

Comment: What a tough question.  How would you even begin?